# The set of odd primes p such that -5 is a quadratic residue mod p

Tags: quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

For any odd prime p -5 is a quadratic residue mod p $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\frac{-5}{p})$=1

By multiplicaticity of the legendre symbol $(\frac{-5}{p})$=$(\frac{-1}{p})$*$(\frac{5}{p})$

What i know:

$(\frac{-1}{p})$=1, if p $\equiv$1 (mod 4)

$(\frac{-1}{p})$=-1, if p $\equiv$3 (mod 4)

$(\frac{5}{p})$=1, if p $\equiv\pm$1 (mod 5)

$(\frac{5}{p})$=-1, if p $\equiv\pm$2 (mod 5)

I also know that -5 is a quadratic recidue mod p if and only mod p if and only if p$\equiv$1, 3, 7, 9 (mod 20)

I have tried back and forth to solve this in a nice way.. 
I know that quadratic reciprocity can be helpful to this solution... I just cant understand how I should show it. Can anyone with the information that I have stated above help to show that: -5 is a quadratic recidue mod p if and only mod p if and only if p$\equiv$1, 3, 7, 9 (mod 20)

Comment: That should be $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=-1,\text{ if }p\equiv \pm 2\bmod 5$, no?  Actually those $\bmod 5$ congruences already use quadratic reciprocity.  What you need is the Chinese Remainder theorem to join appropriate combinations of those congruences together $\bmod 20$

Comment: of cource $\pm2$ :) How should i use Chinese remainder theorem to combine appropiate combinations?  @sharding4

Comment: You need either both $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$ to be $1$ or both to be $-1$.  You have congruence conditions for each case, e.g. $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and $p\equiv 4\bmod 5$.  That says $p\equiv 9\bmod 20$.

Comment: And $(\frac{5}{p}) = (\frac{p}{5})$ essentially [follows from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_Quadratic_Gauss_Sums) $\sqrt{5} = \sum_{n=0}^4 \zeta_5^{n^2}$. Not sure how to adapt it for $(\frac{-1}{p})$ and $(\frac{-5}{p})$ though.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through every case in turn. E.g., if $p\equiv 7\pmod{20}$
then $p\equiv3\pmod 4$ and $p\equiv 2\pmod 5$ so $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac5p\right)=-1$, etc. Don't forget to do
the cases where we expect $\left(\frac{-5}p\right)=-1$, for example
if $p\equiv17\pmod{20}$ then then $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ and $p\equiv 2\pmod 5$ so $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=1$ and $\left(\frac5p\right)=-1$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps, other than $2,$  the primes are those that can be written as either
$$ p = x^2 + 5 y^2 $$ or
$$ p = 2 u^2 + 2uv + 3 v^2 $$
in integers, not necessarily positive.